# I want to create a column with the name of [PERIOD] = Month - year

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a column with the name of [PERIOD] = Month - year and this column show output like {calculation - 1 to 20 date in X Month the select X Month, 21 to 28,30,31 date then select X+1 Month}

Comment: I think there is no one against this - create. Or do you have a question

Answer (score 0):

> select d,if(DATE_FORMAT(d,'%d')<=20,DATE_FORMAT(d,'%m'),DATE_FORMAT(d,'%m')+1) d2 from tablename;